# Apple push notification OnNotificationSent event not raising after deploy to EC2

Tags: ios, amazon-ec2, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I am building a web service using PushSharp to do apple push notification.

Everything works fine on my localhost. device is receiving notification as expected every time.
Events raised as expected.
However after the code is deployed to AWS EC2 instance (our staging server) the push stopped working. 
and the OnNotificationSent is no longer raised neither.

My local and Stage both using same sandbox certificates.
We have checked and opened both ports 2195 and 2196. with no luck so far.

I am missing anything here?